# Does an ethernet network switch have its own MAC address?

Tags: networking

I am currently a uni student in a dorm and we're only allowed to have one device connected to the ethernet.  The way it controls that, is through a website where you have to register the MAC address of the computer or device you want to use ethernet on.  Ideally I would like to have multiple devices connected via ethernet.

I have a gigabit desktop switch and I was wondering whether that had its own MAC address so I could subvert the single ethernet connected device restriction.  Does it have its own MAC address or does the network still see the individual MAC addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the mac address is just a physical footprint. It's, to say, the unique name of a device.

You could get a router, register its MAC and then use NAT to forward the packets to multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

L2 Switches have mac addresses for certain functions like telnet, snmp etc. Some manufacturers have just one, cisco uses a lot of mac addresses for their devices, 1 function - 1 mac.
  So, what model of switch you have?

Comment: The switch is a Tp-link 5-port gigabit desktop switch

Comment: I'm afraid to disappoint you but in your case you need a router to have multiple device connected. For now network devices of your university still see mac of your PC even if you connected thru the switch.

Comment: Can you turn off the wireless on routers and if you can, could you maybe recommend some?

Comment: Routers don't need to have wireless to work, and neither have functionality to dial for a connection. Just forward packets.
In fact, when I connect my phone to my computer via USB, the computer acts as a router, forwarding internet to the device. Just make sure you get a router which supports configuring a NAT network. Ask in the store.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco Switch has many ethernet ports. Where naming conversion is fast-Ethernet 0/0 etc.

Every port has MAC/Physical address. See screenshot:
[image]

For more information, you can check out: [here](https://knowinforms.blogspot.com/2020/12/what-is-address-resolution-protocol-arp.html)